# Implement simple login page using cookie with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I know this might be a repetitive question but I have read a lot of articles. I have usernames I want to save in cookie and use them in other HTML pages. I just want the username to be printed on StudentPage and other pages.

this is app.py

```
@app.route('/StudentLogin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def StudentLogin():

    # res = make_response(render_template("StudentLogin.html"))
    # res.set_cookie('username', request.form.get("username"))
    # return res

    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    if (username == 'Atheer' and password == '10') or (username == 'username' and password == 'password') or (username == 'Yahya' and password == '30'):
        # studentname = LoginTable(username, password)
        # db.session.add(studentname)
        # db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('StudentPage'))
    else:
        return render_template("StudentLogin.html")

@app.route('/StudentPage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def StudentPage():
    # username = request.cookies.get('somecookiename')
    # return '<h1>welcome ' + username + '</h1>'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        student = studentAnswerTable(request.form['studentMCQquestion'], request.form['InstructorMCQanswer'], request.form['ISOptionA'], request.form['ISOptionB'], request.form['ISOptionC'], request.form['studentMCQanswer'])
        db.session.add(student)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template("StudentPage.html", quickQuizQuestions=quickQuizQuestions.query.order_by(-quickQuizQuestions.id).limit(1).all())
```

this is StudentLogin.html

```
<script>
function setCookie(username,cvalue) {
  document.cookie =  cname + "=" + document.getElementById("username").value + ";" ;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  var user=getCookie("username");
}

    function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var valid = false;
        var unArray = ["Atheer", "username", "Yahya"];
        var pwArray = ["10", "password", "30"];
        for (var i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++) {
            if ((username == unArray[i]) && (password == pwArray[i])) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid)
        {
        window.alert('Hi ' +username + ', Login was successful');
        window.location.href = "StudentPage.html"
        }
        else
        {
        window.alert('Login failed, please try again');
        window.location.href = "StudentLogin.html"
        }
return false;
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="checkCookie()">
<form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "POST" name="myform">
<div class="container1">
<h1>Student Login </h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username">
      <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" >
<br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" onclick="validate()" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit">

  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried to create the cookie using Javascript & from the python file but have no success :(

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Be a bit more descriptive. What are you trying to save in the cookie? What is the method that this code should be used? Having some sample input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @Sam i want to save usernames. its a login page when the user logs in it will say "Hello Atheer". I'm not sure what method and how to use it that's why i asked. usernames logins are fixed `var unArray = ["Atheer", "username", "Yahya"];`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are implementing user authentication, you can use Flask's `session` (encrypted cookie) to save and get data. Here is a minimal example from [flask-examples](https://github.com/greyli/flask-examples/blob/master/http/app.py#L136-L156):

```
from flask import session

# log in user
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    session['logged_in'] = True
    return redirect(url_for('hello'))


# protect view
@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    if 'logged_in' not in session:
        abort(403)
    return 'Welcome to admin page.'


# log out user
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        session.pop('logged_in')
    return redirect(url_for('hello'))
```

For your code:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/StudentLogin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def StudentLogin():

    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    
    session['username'] = username  # set the cookie  <---

    if (username == 'Atheer' and password == '10') or (username == 'username' and password == 'password') or (username == 'Yahya' and password == '30'):
        # studentname = LoginTable(username, password)
        # db.session.add(studentname)
        # db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('StudentPage'))
    else:
        return render_template("StudentLogin.html")

@app.route('/StudentPage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def StudentPage():
    username = session.get('username')  # get the cookie  <---
    return '<h1>welcome ' + username + '</h1>'
```